# Using GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT(*) >1 to select duplicate and non-duplicate field

Tags: oracle, group-by, count, having-clause

Below is the data in `CUST_REF` table

`CUST ID   REF ID
    1        7
    2        2
    3        5
    4        5
    5        5`

Below query will return `3   5` and `4   5`

```
SELECT CUST_ID, REF_ID
FROM CUST_REF
WHERE REF_ID IN 
(select ref_id from CUST_REF
 group by ref_id
 having (count(*) > 1))
AND CUST_ID != REF_ID;
```

How about if want to return `1   7` `2   2` `5   5`? I make below query it only able to return `1   7` and `2   2`

```
SELECT CUST_ID, REF_ID
FROM CUST_REF
WHERE CUST_ID = REF_ID
AND REF_ID NOT IN 
(select ref_id from CUST_REF
group by ref_id
having (count(*) > 1))
UNION
SELECT CUST_ID, REF_ID
FROM CUST_REF
WHERE CUST_ID != REF_ID
AND REF_ID NOT IN 
(select ref_id from CUST_REF
group by ref_id
having (count(*) > 1));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to select rows whose REF_ID isn't duplicated, as well as rows whose REF_ID = CUST_ID. If that's so, how about this?

```
SQL> with cust_ref(cust_id, ref_id) as
  2  (select 1, 7 from dual union
  3   select 2, 2 from dual union
  4   select 3, 5 from dual union
  5   select 4, 5 from dual union
  6   select 5, 5 from dual
  7  )
  8  select cust_id, ref_id
  9  from cust_ref
 10  where ref_id not in (select ref_id
 11                       from cust_ref
 12                       group by ref_id
 13                       having count(*) > 1
 14                      )
 15     or ref_id = cust_id;

   CUST_ID     REF_ID
---------- ----------
         1          7
         2          2
         5          5

SQL>
```

Comment: Great, i was stucked, should use `OR` instead of  combining with 3 `UNION`

Comment: I'm glad if it helped.