# Returning the full record of each duplicated row by selecting the table and joining it to the duplicates?

Tags: sql, duplicates, sql-server-2019

The first query works. Query A is based on a post from StackOverflow ([Using GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT(*) >1 to select duplicate and noon-duplicate field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50385337/using-group-by-and-having-count-1-to-select-duplicate-and-noon-duplicate-fie)).

But is it possible to return the full record of each duplicated row by selecting the table and joining it to the duplicates? That's what I'm attempting in Query B. I'm trying to do so on two fields. Is it possible to accomplish this with the HAVING clause constructed this way? I'm a n00b. Any advice or education would be appreciated.

Query A) Based on an example from StackOverflow:

```
SELECT InstanceID, InstanceSequenceNumber
FROM [dbo].[ANBasics]
WHERE InstanceID IN
  (SELECT InstanceID FROM [dbo].[ANBasics]
    GROUP BY InstanceID
    HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1))
ORDER BY InstanceID
```

Query B) What I'm trying to accomplish:

```
SELECT A.*, COUNT(*) AS B 
FROM [dbo].[ANBasics] AS A
  JOIN( 
    SELECT [InstanceID], [InstanceSequenceNumber], COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[ANBasics] 
    GROUP BY [InstanceID], [InstanceSequenceNumber]
    HAVING (B > 1) )
      ON A.[InstanceID] = B.[InstanceID]
      AND A.[InstanceSequenceNumber] = B.[InstanceSequenceNumber]
ORDER BY A.[InstanceID]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, window functions are the simplest solution:

```
SELECT ab.*
FROM (SELECT ab.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY InstanceID, InstanceSequenceNumber) as cnt
      FROM [dbo].[ANBasics] ab
     ) ab
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

If you want this for duplicates of two columns:

```
SELECT ab.*
FROM (SELECT ab.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY InstanceID) as cnt
      FROM [dbo].[ANBasics] ab
     ) ab
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Comment: These queries are terrific, thank you. It never occurred to me to use OVER (PARTITION BY). Thank you for introducing me to the term "window functions".  I have one n00b question: could you explain why it was necessary to add the table name, AB, behind the closing bracket of the FROM (SELECT) statement? I've never done that before, and can't help but wonder how it makes these queries work so beautifully. If you know of some  documentation to point me to, I wouldn't complain. I sometimes lack the vocabulary to ask what I want to ask.

Comment: @Ganymede . . . SQL Server requires a table alias after a subquery in the `FROM` clause (I think it is a good idea anyway).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer these n00b questions.